# Unable to call parametric-based jquery based function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, function

I have a working jquery function which I can call like this through php

```
if (!order) 

        {   echo '<script>
$(function() {
$this = $("#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0");
//  parent tab
var parent = $("#accordion").parent();
//parent.adderror();

// the content
$this.adderror();

// the header
var header = $this.attr("aria-labelledby");
$("#"+header).adderror();


// the tab
var tab = parent.attr("aria-labelledby");
$("#"+tab).parent().adderror();
});

    </script>';}
```

I want to make this a global function (even better if defined externally in a .js file) that I can call from wherever I want in my php, which takes the panel as a parameter.

So I would basically call - show_error("#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0"). How could I do this? When I tried defining function, and then calling it - there was no change whatsoever. Was using through techinques defined here to no avail ([var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname))

Thanks in advance

Ok, I have now an error.js file, which I have linked appropriately ( )

```
function show_error(selector) {
var $this = $(selector);

//  parent tab
var parent = $("#accordion").parent();

//parent.adderror();

// the content
$this.adderror();

// the header
var header = $this.attr("aria-labelledby");
$("#"+header).adderror();


// the tab
var tab = parent.attr("aria-labelledby");
$("#"+tab).parent().adderror();
}
```

Comment: FWIW, your function falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare your `$this` variable.

Comment: What's `parent` in the line `var tab = parent.attr("aria-labelledby");`? You haven't shown anything showing where you're getting that.

Comment: My bad, thought I would just post the snippet. Ended up confusing you all, I'm sorry. Just made the relevant edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your external .js file would look like this:

```
function show_error(selector) {
    var $this = $(selector);
    //  parent tab
    var parent = $("#accordion").parent();
    //parent.adderror();

    // the content
    $this.adderror();

    // the header
    var header = $this.attr("aria-labelledby");
    $("#"+header).adderror();

    // the tab
    var tab = parent.attr("aria-labelledby");
    $("#"+tab).parent().adderror();
}
```

Comment: I tried something very similar, didn't work. Will try again now.

Comment: @PratikBothra: Well, again, there's the question of where you're getting `parent`. But fundamentally, that **does** work, barring other issues on your page not shown in your question.

Comment: To help debug the code, I added an alert($this) in the function, and this is what I get - [object Object] as the alert. So the function is being called, but no change is happening at the moment. Pretty sure the alert message, shouldn't show that, or should it?

Comment: @PratikBothra: It should, `$this` is a jQuery instance (object), since it's the return value of jQuery's `$` function. That's why you can call methods on it.

Comment: alert(selector) is giving me #ui-accordion-accordion-panel-0, if that helps

Comment: @PratikBothra: It's something about your page that you haven't shown. Nothing for it but to properly debug it. (`alert`-style debugging went out years ago; use the debugger built into your browser to single-step through code, set breakpoints, inspect objects, etc., etc.)

Comment: Here, check this out http://jsfiddle.net/buKLE/17/ ....Can you try making an internal function here, and see if it works by passing #ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1 to the function?

Comment: @PratikBothra: Exactly zero issue: http://jsfiddle.net/buKLE/18/ I copied the code from my answer above, pasted it in a `script` tag, and replaced the code in your `ready` handler with `show_error("#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1");` Works a treat (assuming it's supposed to make Tab1 red).

Comment: I feel foolish, I was doing just show_error("#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1"); instead of $(function() {
    show_error("#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1");
}); Thanks anyways

Comment: @PratikBothra: Ah, that would call the code too early, before the DOM elements were in place. (It would be fine if you moved that script tag all the way to the bottom of the page.) Happy coding,